# Make elements hidding using Z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-transitions

Got an issue here regarding making other div-elements hidden when and other div has been visible.
As you see in my code below, when f.ex. star trek have been visible, I want pacific rim and world war z to disappear using z-index.

My HTML code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>BluShop</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <header id="header">
        <h1>BluShop</h1>
    </header>

    <section id="leftContent">
        <div id="pacificrimContent">
            <h2>Pacific Rim</h2>
            <img alt="pacificrim image" src="../bilder/pacificRim.jpg">
            <p>Blahblahblah</p>
        </div>
        <div id="startrekContent">
            <h2>Star Trek</h2>
            <img alt="startrek image" src="../bilder/starTrek.jpg">
            <p>blahblahblah</p>
        </div>
        <div id="worldwarzContent">
            <h2>World War Z</h2>
            <img alt="worldwarz image" src="../bilder/worldWarZ.jpg">
            <p>blahblahblah</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <aside id="rightContent">
        <div id="pacificrimPoster">
            <a href="#pacificrimContent"><img alt="pacificrim poster" src="../bilder/pacificRim.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="startrekPoster">
            <a href="#startrekContent"><img alt="startrek poster" src="../bilder/starTrek.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="worldwarzPoster">
            <a href="#worldwarzContent"><img alt="worldwarz poster" src="../bilder/worldWarZ.jpg"></a>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <footer id="footer">
    </footer>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS code

```
    @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    margin: 0;
    }

#container{
    width: 960px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgb(78, 80, 85);
    border: solid 1px rgb(213, 214, 215);
    }

#header{
    height: 60px;
    background-color: rgb(66, 69, 74);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }   

#header h1{
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    color: rgb(14, 177, 238);   
    }

#leftContent{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;;
    height: 460px;
    width: 780px;
    background-color: rgb(230, 231, 232);
    }

#leftContent h2{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    }

#leftContent img{
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 20px 10px 10px;
    width: 310px;
    height: 420px;
    }

#leftContent p{
    margin: -4px 20px 10px 0px;
    }


#pacificrimContent, #startrekContent, #worldwarzContent{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: height .5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: height .5s ease-in;
    }                   

#startrekContent, #worldwarzContent{
    z-index: -1;
    height: 0; 
    }

#rightContent{
    float: right;
    width: 140px;
    height: 460px;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color: rgb(230, 231, 232);
    }   

#rightContent img{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px    
    }   

#pacificrimContent:target, #startrekContent:target, #worldwarzContent:target{
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    }

#footer{
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0;  
    background-color: rgb(16, 163, 210);
    clear: both;
    }
```

As you see I need Pacific Rim to be the standard movie that show up when people vist the website, and the other should be visible when I target them. Then the movie I target should be visible. Per now, Pacific Rim is ALWAYS visible and in the background of the other movie.

So if i f.ex. choose to target the star trek movie, and then so the world war z movie. I see the Pacific Rim movie behind when the transition is working.

I am not allowed to use javascript, so is there a way I can get this working?
Thanks!

jsfiddle.net/f8ns4 - JSFiddle to show what i mean!

Comment: A JSFiddle with actual images would be useful because it's very hard to see what you are trying to do based on the raw code.

Comment: Why `z-index` when there are more targeted solutions. Depending on how you want the page to behave you can use one of the following: `opacity:0;` `visibility:hidden;` `display:none;`

Comment: I agree with @SmokeyPHP, but I would go for `display: none` or jquery `$('#element').fadeOut()`

Comment: You should do more research on z-index if you really wish to go that way. There are some CSS properties (like positionning) that need to be  specifically set when you want to work with z-index. As pointed by Smokey, there are other and often used alternatives to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am not allowed to use javacscript and if I use display, the transition is not work correctly. Maybe visibility would be great, but I can try put it on JSFiddle to show.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f8ns4/ As you se when I press the other poster the text just go over the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your individual movie divs a background color so you cant see whats underneath it.

```
#pacificrimContent, #startrekContent, #worldwarzContent{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: height .5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: height .5s ease-in;
    background-color: rgb(230, 231, 232);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f8ns4/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as you see, still the Pacific Rim cover appears under each ease in. But maybe this is the best solution as long as I don't are allowed to use javascript.

Comment: @Emilio Yeah I dont think you can do better than that without JS

Comment: Ah, okei. But do you know why the left content extends when clicking on star trek or world war z? The grey area becomes something like 5px longer.

Comment: Update: I moved the background-color into the #startrekContent, #worldwarzContent and that fixed the problem! Thanks for your time

Comment: @Emilio Okay I was going to say remove 

`#startrekContent, #worldwarzContent{
 z-index: -1;
  height: 0; 
 }`

As it is useless now and it also fixes the problem